# Applescript Remote Click

Tags: macos, mouse, applescript

I'm trying to get remove mouse events working and I'm attempting to use this little script:

```
set machineB to "eppc://user:pw@myothermac.local"
tell application "Finder" of machine machineB
    say "Hello This is so stupid"
end tell
tell application "System Events" of machine machineB
    click at {100, 100}
end tell
```

The script `say`'s fine, but throws the following error:

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t continue click." number -1708

–1708 <reference> doesn’t understand the <commandName> message.
```

What am I doing wrong? I can use it to "click" on my own machine (at least it doesn't throw errors)?

---

[Edit]

this is related to my other question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051587/apple-events-to-control-mouse-remotely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. Applescript and its `tell` blocks work in the context of the Mac running the application; you can send commands to the Finder on your home Mac because you are running it, but you can't send commands to the instance of Finder on a target Mac. If you are able to run an application located on the target machine from your home Mac, then the application will behave as if it is being run on the home Mac.

If you are looking to do complex remote actions, then I suggest Apple Remote Desktop or another similar method.

Comment: Uhm, but the other mac machine executes the `say` command perfectly!

Comment: I think you were lucky on that one, to be perfectly honest. What you're asking here is really odd, especially for Applescript.

Comment: I dunno, I see tons of stuff online about controlling iTunes remotely.  Plus there's an [O'Reily chapter on it.](http://books.google.com/books?id=zQy4mgqIccsC&pg=PA388&lpg=PA388&dq=control+remote+machine+with+applescript&source=bl&ots=scf1qRTJM1&sig=cL1n2zLnXZIX6hDUXUOITTRM_qk&hl=en&ei=70fYTPjiEYK0lQf5p9yRCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBoQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=control%20remote%20machine%20with%20applescript&f=false)

Comment: That edition is four years old now and Apple's Applescript support has slipped considerably since Automater was released (2005). Not all things work as advertised these days.

Comment: I can see why this should not work. This to me would be a big security hole I wouldn't want someone to run applescripts on my machine

Comment: @mcgrailm, you still have to log onto the machine via `eppc://user:pw@myothermac.local` in order to run it.

Comment: True, but grubbing around files and actually running processes are to very different things.

Comment: @Phillip, well it's not the answer I want but it's the correct one.  Thanks.